# Running Parameterized test seems to hold because of a browser lock?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running some tests against multiple browsers, in this case Chrome and Firefox.

It seems thought that after Chrome finishes the tests, Firefox will hang until I force close Chrome's browser window.  Then The firefox tests will run.

What could be doing this, and how can i prevent it?

Below is the code I have:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyFirstTest {
  private String _platform;
  private WebDriver _driver;
  private String url = "http://localhost:8000/web/";
  private String descSelector = "todo-form paper-input input";

  public MyFirstTest(String platform, WebDriver driver){
    _platform = platform;
    _driver = driver;
  }

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection testList(){
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            {"chrome", new ChromeDriver(DesiredCapabilities.chrome())},
            {"firefox", new FirefoxDriver(DesiredCapabilities.firefox())}
    });
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddToDo() {
    _driver.navigate().to(url);
   WebEleemnet ele = _driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(descSelector)).get(0);
  }
}
```

It seems to hang up on the navigate call.  I think there is something wrong with the scope, but im not really sure what the issue is.  The way this is running, i thought it would be async and would not affect each other.

Currently Running: Selenuim 3.0.0beta3, Firefox 49.0.1

Comment: Seems to be working with FF45 and Selenium 2.50.1

Comment: When having a bunch of Tests, it will sometimes lock because the last browser doesnt close.